Defining representation of locally compact group on a pre-Hilbert space
Ramakrishnan and Valenza's Fourier Analysis on Number Fields defines a topological representation of a locally compact group only on a locally convex topological vector space. But they also talk of topological representations of locally compact groups on pre-Hilbert spaces (vector spaces endowed with Hermitian forms). I could not find anywhere that every pre-Hilbert space is locally convex. So I'm not sure how this is going to work.

Pre-Hilbert spaces are normed spaces, and every normed space is locally convex, as norm topologies are generated by open balls, which are balanced, absorbing convex sets.

@TheoBendit Thank you.
